# What's the right way to base64 Encoding in Cococa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, base64

I'm enconding this data with this line:

```
NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", email, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding];
```

for a basic HTTP Authentication

It works quite perfect but i'm getting this warning:

> warning: 'NSData' may not respond to '-base64Encoding'

is there other way for encoding or how do i remove this warning?

Comment: As an aside, base64 is no more secure than plain text for transmitting data across a network.  You need some sort of cryptographic means of transmitting the data in the real World.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is correct: NSData does not respond to that message. As you can see in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/), NSData does not implement base-64 encoding and decoding.

You'll need to either use OpenSSL's BIO API to do the job, or use a third-party framework or library that wraps that (or a separate encoder/decoder) in an easy Cocoa API. A [Google search for “Cocoa Base64”](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&num=20&q=Cocoa+Base64) will turn up some options.